# Launch terminal window from go lang program?

Tags: linux, shell, api, go

I want to have a functionality in which i will create an go program running on linux system. When that program is running it will download a `zip folder` from server & extract it to user `HOME` directory. That extracted folder will have a shell script file eg. `Update.sh`. 
Now i want once that file is extracted i want to open the terminal & run the shell script automatically which resides inside extracted folder. Kindly gudie me can i do that ?

Comment: That is in general impossible (all web browsers protect the user from locally running programs). The web service is not running on your Linux laptop (but on a remote Linux server). You can find programs (such as libonion [oterm](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/wiki/Oterm)) doing what you want, and you could rewrite them in Go

Comment: But go is running that service. From go lang i want to launch the terminal

Comment: Congratulations. Either reproduce what `oterm` is doing (and that may require complex things like WebSockets) or give up your goal. You certainly should take much more time in understanding [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and combine them as `oterm` does

Comment: Don't forget that in general the web server and the web browsers are running on different computers. The web is designed to make impossible for a web service to run programs on the browser's machine (that would be a huge security hole)

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the Go standard library? Your best bet is [os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/). I don't know how feasible it would be to open another terminal and launch the script in *it*, but you can pipe the output of the command launched by os/exec to the stdout of the terminal in which the go program was launched.

From your question, it sounds like the go program downloading and running the script is already being run by the user on the local machine. If this is not the case, then the above will not work.